# Changing barWidth based on data

Tags: echarts

For line chart it's possible to change the symbolSize using a callback function. I was hoping to do the same with bar width in a bar chart. However, as per documentation only a fixed width or a percent is possible but there seems to be no callback option. Is there any other way to dynamically change the bar width based on data?

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible from the point of view of common sense. Each graph is designed to visualize a specific type of data. When you change bar width the Bar chart stops being a Bar chart and turns into something that is of value only for you. Most likely, you just selected the wrong type of graph to display your data. You can see most of the existing chart types on the website: https://datavizproject.com

If you insist that this is of the utmost importance, then you have a [custom series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom) for any idea. For example "dynamic bar width" also know as rare [Profit chart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profit).

[image]

Comment: It's possible to add extra information to a chart using color, size and symbol type. Size is the size of the symbol for line chart. For bar chart, there is no symbol so size can be applied only to the entire bar itself. So, I wouldn't go so far as saying "impossible". I was looking for a way to achieve it without customization. Thanks for your custom series reference though.

Comment: If you remove the corners from a square, it will no longer be a square.